# Vb.Net Form Inside Panel Resizing Issues

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble with a VB form not properly resizing inside of a panel. When the window is resized, the form does not follow. It stays anchored to the top left. The panel however does properly resize.

Normal Size - http://s23.postimg.org/7pbwa6znv/ct1.png
Resized - http://s18.postimg.org/kvek5ga95/ct2.png

Here is how I am showing Form2

```
Form2.TopLevel = False
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Form2)
Form2.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Form2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Form2.Show()
```

I have attempted to use the following, with no success.
`Dim f As New Form2 With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False}
f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
f.Show()`

Currently how I am getting around this issue is on resize, close form2, then reopen it. Beyond this not being a proper work around, all data inside of Form2 is lost when resized due to it closing.

```
    If Form2.Visible = True Then
        Form2.Close()
        Form2.TopLevel = False
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Form2)
        Form2.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Form2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Form2.Show()
    End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    Dim form2 As New Form
    form2.TopLevel = False
    form2.BackColor = Color.Red
    form2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    form2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom
    form2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top
    form2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left
    form2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right
    Panel1.Controls.Add(form2)


    form2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    form2.Show()
```

Comment: Gave that a go and unfortunately, no change. Is there a possibility it could be due to Form2's properties?

Comment: Could it be that your panel is not anchored to top, bottom, left , right?

Comment: Panel1 was set to Fill instead of T,B,L,R. I made the change and no dice.